# Show that for compact operator $\|A_nB-AB\|\rightarrow0$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compact-operators

Let $A_{(n)}:\mathcal B\rightarrow \mathcal B$ be a linear bounded operators such that for any $f\in \mathcal B$, $A_nf\rightarrow Af$. Show that then for any compact operator $B$

$$\|A_nB-AB\|\rightarrow0$$

Any tips how to show this?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182641/compact-operators-and-uniform-convergence

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of $A_nT$ to $AT$ in operator norm for compact $T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478359/convergence-of-a-nt-to-at-in-operator-norm-for-compact-t)