# Existence of compact operator with eigenvelues determined by a given sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Could anyone help me with the following exercise? Any help will be very welcome:

Given a sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$ so that $\alpha_n \to 0$, show that exists a compact operator $T$ with spectrum $\sigma(T)=\{\alpha_n\} \cup \{0\}$

[Edit 1]: I found a useful construction in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478359/convergence-of-a-nt-to-at-in-operator-norm-for-compact-t)

[Edit 2]: $T:l^2 \rightarrow l^2, T((a_n)_{n=1}^\infty)=(\lambda_na_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ does the job!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hint: Try a diagonal operator on $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$.